# If the changes wiil affect moodle migration

Tags: moodle

I am using moodle 3.2 version. I did some changes in moodle database tables.For example i have added Schoolyear column in mdl_course table for my requirement purpose.When moodle migrate to next version the changes will affect or not?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is generally a bad idea to mess around with core Moodle database tables. It can cause problems during upgrades (and will not be included in backups, unless you change the core code as well), so it is usually better to store extra data in new tables.

That being said, there are occasions where it is really not practical to do anything else, and, usually, it does not cause too actual problems.  The harder part is the merging of the core code changes that work with the changed database tables.

Comment: so,when we upgrade moodle new added column will remove. am i right?

Comment: No - newly added columns will be untouched, which is why there can be problems (very rare when adding new fields, but it can happen).